# Infinite Loop not breaking out of nested for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, nested, fuzzy-search

My apologies for the length and for what is I'm sure a simple problem.

I am carrying out a word search using the fuzzysearch and Pyenchant modules.

I am trying to convert a nested for loop method to one that uses a for and while loop. I am failing, getting an infinite loop.

The basic method is as follows

> For a word in a sentence, check if the word exists in some dictionary.
>
> If the word does not exist, generate word suggestions using Enchant.
>
> For each suggestion, calculate the ratio of similarity between the generated word and the original word.
>
> If the ratio is high enough, stop generating suggestions, and add the new word to a list.
>
> Do this for all words in the sentence

For example, for the string: `A = 'A lvels in Mths and Histtory`

The Output would be: `['A','levels','in','maths','and','history']`

I have managed to get this to work in the following way:

```
# Imports:
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import enchant
from enchant.tokenize import get_tokenizer
tknzr = get_tokenizer("en")
d = enchant.Dict("en")

A = 'A lvels in Mths and Histtory'

B = []

# Loop through all words in A
for word, position in tknzr(A):

    # Does word exist in Dictionary?
    if d.check(word) is False:

        # generate a suggestion and calculate the 'fuzz factor'
        for suggestion in d.suggest(word):
            ratio = fuzz.ratio(suggestion, word)

            # If ratio is high enough, add word to list B and move to next word in sentence
            if ratio > 75:
                B.append(suggestion)
                break

# If word is in dictionary, just add
    else:
        B.append(word)

Out >>> ['A','levels','in','maths','and','history']
```

Good so far.

I would like to convert the above into one that uses a while and for loop. This would then be of the form: Generate new words, until you reach some threshold.

I tried the following:

```
for word,position in tknzr(A):

    if d.check(word) is False:

        ratio = 0
        while ratio <= 75:

            for suggestion in d.suggest(word):

                print "Suggestion: ", suggestion
                ratio = fuzz.ratio(suggestion, word)

                B.append(word)
    else:
        B.append(word)
```

This however gives me an infinite loop of suggestions for the word Histtory.

```
Out >>> Suggestion:  History
Out >>> Suggestion:  Historicity
Out >>> Suggestion:  Historic
Out >>> Suggestion:  Historian
Out >>> Suggestion:  Sophistry
Out >>> Suggestion:  Histrionic
Out >>> Suggestion:  Histogram
Out >>> The above forever
```

The problem is as follows:

The `for suggestion in d.suggest(word):` loop will always run to completion, *before* the higher `while` loop can check the ratio values.

This means that the final `ratio` value checked, is that of the last word suggested e.g. for `Histtory` it is the ratio of `Hisstory` and `Histogram`. As this is <75, the `while` loop condition is still true, and so repeats forever. I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to fix it.

How can I change this code so that it works as in the first example?
I should add: My goal here is speed: I will be evaluating 10s of millions of sentences.

Many thanks for your reading.

Comment: Does the code work? -> If yes, good, don't touch it. Did the code stop working after some changes you made? -> Oops, revert the changes. Does the code work now? -> Is yes, good, don't touch it, otherwise revert a change and try again?

Comment: @ForceBru you are not wrong... perhaps this is more of a question for Code Review?

Comment: @Bouletta: you deleted your answer before I had a chance to respond: it looked good!

Comment: @CharlesMorris Not really, I had not read the end of your question so I was just explaining that again. to fix the infinite loop you can change to the following line :
`ratio = max(ratio, fuzz.ratio(suggestion, word))`
but this won't improve your performance which I understand is what you want

Comment: @CharlesMorris I don't know of a way to do what you want without breaking implicitly out of your for loop but then you might as well use the first version of your code

Comment: @bouletta That was a good way of getting the 'recursion' i.e. go over all words and update ratio if the new word has a higher ratio than that already saved. Another problem is that doing it this way `ratio = max...` sacrifices the inbuilt accuracy of enchant, i.e. the first suggestion should is what enchant thinks is the most likely. Doing anything with fuzzywuzzy ind of bypasses that, but thats another thing altogether. Thanks for your input: I appreciate it.

Comment: @bouletta In response to your second comment: I agree. I'm trying to make it too complicated.

Comment: @CharlesMorris Yeah which is why I deleted my answer :)
But why do you absolutely want a while loop? To the best of my knowledge your initial code is legit and changing to an equivalent while loop won't improve the performance (I might be wrong)

Comment: @bouletta I thought it would be faster. It looks now like it is not worth the effort. Thanks for helping me 'sound board' suggestions!